# Apache can't start "could not bind to address [::]:443" though no process is using it, and netcat can openit

Tags: linux, apache, centos

my version of apache

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 20 2018 18:10:38
```

when I run the command `lsof -i :443` it returns nothing

but if I try to run apache (directly by running `httpd` I got the error, I verified with `ps aux` that there was no previous httpd/apache process already running)

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
```

However if i try to run a `netcat` process on 443 `nc 0.0.0.0 -l 443` , it does open and I can send data

I'm a bit lost on what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it

`Listen 443` was present two times among the different configuration files of apache

it's a pity apache does not have a more explicit error/warning message (i.e "option defined two times" etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems another process is using port 443 on your server.

```
netstat -anp | grep 443
```

output will be

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN

**disable port 443** and start

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

Comment: as said in my original question, there was not,  as when using netcat i was able to open the port ,  (and lsopen / netstat where confirming me that no process was using the port), it was actually apache2 that was trying to open a second time the port it was already using itself, because the instruction listen 443 was present 2 times )